# azure windows vm for supporting docker linux and windows containers same time

Tags: azure-devops

Which azure windows Virtual Machine supports to run Linux and Windows containers same time?

I have tried with windows 10 pro-1809 by installing docker for desktop and also docker toolbox.
Also azure windows 2016 with docker toolbox.

Comment: Hi manikandan Is my answer helpful to you?If you have any question about it ,please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think the windows vm provided by auzre should not support running Linux and Windows containers at the same time.Because linux and window use different cores.Only azure windows vm core support, you can run linux and windows containers at the same time. Azure windows server is built on its newly established core, not exactly the same as windows server.

So if you want to run the linux and wndows containers at the same time, you can build a virtual machine locally. The local VM depends on the local server. Many issues related to container are recommended to build in the windows server environment.